# Time/Resource/Machine problem

Tags: linear-algebra

I am unable to solve this question.

> If $3$ people can work on $120$ machines over $10$ days to finish, then in how many days much does $5$ people working on $90$ machines finish the same task ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

This [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-hour) page might help.

- It takes $(3 \text{ people}) (10 \text{ days}) = 30 \text{ person-days}$ to finish working on $120 \text{ machines}$.
- Multiplying by $\dfrac{90 \text{ machines}}{120 \text{ machines}} = \dfrac{3}{4}$, we know that it takes $30 \cdot \dfrac{3}{4} = \dfrac{45}{2}\text{ person-days}$ to finish working on $120 \cdot \dfrac{3}{4} = 90 \text{ machines}$.
- Since there are $5 \text{ people}$, it will take $\dfrac{45/2 \text{ person-days}}{5 \text{ people}} = \dfrac{9}{2}=4.5 \text{ days}$ to finish working on $90 \text{ machines}$.